# AS3 - get access to the internal bitmap used by CacheAsBitmap?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

is it possible to get access to Flash's internal bitmap cache of an object when CacheAsBitmap is on ?

eg, something like:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = someDisplayObject.getCachedBitmapData();
if (bmd != null)
    trace("stoked!");
else
    trace("bummer. got to bmd.Draw(someDisplayObject) ourselves.");
```

seems unlikely, but thought i'd ask.

tia,
Orion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to go the draw route.

cacheAsBitmap is only used internally by Flash player to determine how a display object is drawn.